# MethodNotAllowedHttpException Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, exception

I get this `issue` when I submit a post form

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   No message

I have been reading about this issue and most people said that the route should be changed to post which I have from the start and I am getting this **error**

**web.php**:

```
Route::post('/new-trade/submit', 'NewTradesController@submit');
```

**Controller**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NewTradesController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request){
        return 123;
    }
}
```

**Form**:

```
{!! Form::open(['class' => 'needs-validation', 'novalidate', 'id' => 'new-trade-form', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a form, you are not specifying the `action` or `url` where form will post to. You can add action like :

`{!! Form::open(['class' => 'needs-validation', 'url' => '/new-trade/submit', 'novalidate', 'id' => 'new-trade-form', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) !!}`

Also `POST` is the default method for form open. So you can remove `'method' => 'post'` if you would like

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
{!! Form::open([url=>'/new-trade/submit','class' => 'needs-validation', 'novalidate', 'id' => 'new-trade-form', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) !!}
```